# moving focus to interior buttons for accessibility users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

The issue I am having is that I am using three tabs that will allow keyboard focus to be transferred to the first button in the set. The following code is intended to find the href of the button, and target its partner id. Currently, the focus is not being transferred upon click as it should be. Any help is appreciated.

jQuery:

```
  var tab1 = $('#InstitutionDetailButton')
    var tab2 = $('#CurrentRequirementButton')
    var tab3 = $('#AnnualRequirementButton')
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(tab1, tab2, tab3).click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var hash = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
            $(hash).focus(function () {
            $("#" + hash).focus();
            })
            return false
        });
    });
```

html:

buttons:

```
   <span id="InstitutionDetailButton"  href="#InstitutionInfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Institution</span>

   <span id="CurrentRequirementButton" href="#CurrenteligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction">Current Tuition Requirements</span>

   <span id="AnnualRequirementButton" href="#AnnualEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction" >Annual Tuition Requirements</span>
```

Anchor Destinations:

```
 <span id="InstitutionInfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Details</span>

  <span id="CurrentEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction">Eligible programs

   <span id="AnnualEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction"> Eligible Programs</span>Programs</span>
```

Update: for sake of ease of access and refactoring, I removed all of the href connection, and rebuilt using a keypress access function to greatly simplify the issue.

```
  $('#InstitutionDetailButton').keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if ((key == 13) && ("[id=InstitutionDetailButton]")){
            $('#InstitutionInfoBtn').focus();
        }
  }
```

Comment: 1. `$(hash) !== $("#" + hash)` 2. You're only adding a `focus` event handler (if the problem from 1. is fixed)

Comment: @Andreas added the code, but the focus is still not transferring. I also commented out e.stopPropagation(). with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the span does not have a tabindex property the focus() will not work. You can programmatically give span the tabindex property. Once tabindex property is set .focus() will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#InstitutionDetailButton, #CurrentRequirementButton, #AnnualRequirementButton').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $(hash).attr("tabIndex", "1");
    $(hash).focus();
    return false
  });
  
  $(document).on('keyup','#InstitutionInfoBtn',function(){
   alert("Hit");
});
  
});
```

```css
span {
  min-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="InstitutionDetailButton" href="#InstitutionInfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Institution</span>

<span id="CurrentRequirementButton" href="#CurrentEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction">Current Tuition Requirements</span>

<span id="AnnualRequirementButton" href="#AnnualEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction">Annual Tuition Requirements</span>


<span id="InstitutionInfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Details</span>

<span id="CurrentEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction">Eligible programs

   <span id="AnnualEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction"> Eligible Programs</span>Programs</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it still isn't moving keyboard focus to the target properly. I tried switching to tabindex=0 which allows me to target again when moving through, but does not set the target on button click.

Comment: is your actual code similar to the above snippet? the focus does move on click in the solution snippet.

Comment: Yes it is, I realized that I had asked that question incorrectly, I needed the on click event to transfer the keyboard focus to the id that the href is attached to. The rest is intended to prevent page redirect due to use of base tag.

Comment: @Joshua i have updated the example. when you click InstitutionDetailButton span the focus goes to the InstitutionInfoBtn span. I have bind keyup event with this span. Now if you hit a key this event will be fired. Let me know if you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you very much sir, your help is deeply appreciated.